# Print the items that are similiar in a list and a txt file

Tags: python

```
filename = r"D:\PythonFiles\Python_File.txt"
f = open(filename)

List1 = ['E','H']

for line in f:
if line == List1:
    print(line)
```

When I execute this, all that comes up is the entire contents of the txt file:

```
H
E
L
L
O
```

All that should be printed is:

```
H
E
```

Comment: Use the `in` operator `if line in List1:`

Comment: NB if anyone finds this question in search of metrics for similarity, or if that's what you actually want - you could look at edit distances, such as the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). After implementing, you would have to decide on a threshold for similarity between strings, and compare the minimum distance with any string in the list against it.

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen you can also use the [editdistance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance) package, which implements Levenshtein for you, but this is a better definition of "similar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answers above are what you're looking for. However, for completeness and because it is a better way to do what you're asking to do, I'll also propose using a set intersection:

```
In [20]: f = open('file.txt').read().split('\n')  # Since readlines keeps newlines
    ...: interesting = ['E', 'H']
    ...: set(interesting) & set(f)
    ...:
Out[20]: {'E', 'H'}
```

Comment: Correct, this loses any guarantee of order. All the original question asks is "print the items that are similar", so I assume that order isn't essential. @EuanMason, if you need to preserve order, you'll need something like the answers below, otherwise this is probably the most efficient way to do what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` as it tells you if something is *in* something else.

```
filename = r"D:\PythonFiles\Python_File.txt"
f = open(filename)
List1 = ['E','H']

for line in f:
    ## Use the 'in' operator here instead of '=='
    if line in List1:
        print(line)

    ## If List1 is going to be dynamic
    ## else:
    ##     List1.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Iterate File contents Line by Line
for line in f.readlines():
    # Remove leading NewLine and Test if line in List1
    if line.strip() in List1:
       # Print's line with NewLine
       print(line)
```

Comment: You would need to test `line.strip() in List1`, as `line` will have a trailing newline.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
filename = r"D:\PythonFiles\Python_File.txt"
f = open(filename, 'r')
List1 = ['E','H']
for line in f.readlines():
    if line in List1:
        print(line)
```